# How can we play Game of Thrones as a league game?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Our group of players has increased in size quite a lot, and we wanted to start having tournaments and league games. However, we don't want to restrict ourselves to 2 player games only, like Twilight Struggle or Android: Netrunner (even though these are great games!)

**We would like to have a league in Game of Thrones. How would you do it?**

(The simplest answer is "rank everyone and give points to the top 3", or something like that. I'm sure there are better ideas out there.)

Comment: @user1873 Tried your suggestion. Let me know if it's clearer.

Comment: @user1873 tried again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In simplest tournament form

In each round winners advance to next round, losers do not. If an alliance wins, they advance together for that round only. 2nd place matters not...

## For a longer format

Everyone gets to play up to *X* games of *Y* game opportunities. Winners (individual or alliance) get 3 points each, losers get 1. After the *Y*
th opportunity has been played, count up total points. Top 4-6 players by points advance. If more than 6 are tied, have two tables, and divide the tied players between them, and then take the winners from both, and if needed the 2nd place players from both, to make a 3-6 player final.

In each of the *x* games, randomize from those present - I recommend using 3x5 cards with player names on them, and tracking of wins and losses.

### 2nd place - why not?

awarding points for non-victory is a complication that, while it can advance consistently passable players to finals, doesn't actually select for the best players. THe best players are good and consistent.

### What If I want to push for solo wins?

In that case, Solo victory is a 3 point, alliance victory is a 2 point, and anything less is still 1 point

### Why do losers get a point?

Because it pushes them up the rankings for being consistent in showing up. This is a benefit for league play.

### Example

A 13 player league, players A-M, has 6 weeks and enough sets for 3 tables per week. The option to endorse solo wins over alliance wins is in place. Week 6 will be "finals"

Week 1, Everyone's present, and so the tables are 5, 4 and 4. AFGHM, BCIL, and DEJK are the table layouts. A wins solo, BC win as an alliance, and J wins

Week 2, A is sick. Tables are thus 6 each for two tables. BDFHJM and CEGIKL. KL win alliance, BD wins shared.

Week 3, D, K and M are stuck at work.  2 tables, 5 each. ACEIJ BFGHL. AC win shared, G wins solo.

Week 4,  N joins the league (late but enjoys play). there's a storm. Only ADGHN make it. H wins solo.

Week 5, Everyone shows. 5-5-4 tables. ADIKN BEGJM CFHL. A wins shared. BG win shared. H wins solo, as does N.

Final is H (with 9) G (with 8) A B (with 7), C & J (with 6).

```
    Wk  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
    1:  3  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  1  -
    2:  0  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  -
    3:  2  1  2  0  1  1  3  1  1  1  0  1  1  -  
    4:  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  1
    5:  1  2  1  1  1  1  2  3  1  1  1  1  1  3
  Tot:  7  7  6  5  4  4  8  9  4  6  4  5  4  4
```

Now, if run without the penalty for shared, the numbers look like this:

```
    Wk  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
    1:  3  3  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  1  -
    3:  0  3  1  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  1  -
    3:  3  1  3  0  1  1  3  1  1  1  0  1  1  -  
    4:  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  1
    5:  1  3  1  1  1  1  3  3  1  1  1  1  1  3
  tot:  8 10  8  6  4  4  9  9  4  6  5  6  4  4
```

The finals would be B (10), GH (9) AC (8). we don't go to the 6's because that would trigger a second table.

Note that the longer the league plays, the more important consistent play is.

Comment: What is an allied victory? As far as I am aware there can only be one winner in the Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some rule concerning alliances, I think I will go with something like:

- 10 pts for winner,
- 3 pts for second place
- and 1 pts for third

But then I would allow players to promise each other some fraction of these points to others in exchange for help/alliance.

The open question is if that should be done on the last three rounds basis (If both declare help, then after the game points are split or just decided by winners at end).

And remember: You Win or You Die! :)

Comment: I didn't follow the friction of the points rule you mentioned. Could you please give an example?

Comment: I mean that I could promise that If I win I would split earned points (for example 2 points to my ally and 8 for me 2+8=total 10, if he was second then he gets 2+3=5pts and I get 8pts). That rule is added so that making alliances would be fun and to give reason for weaker player to support winner.